# How to have certain anchor tags appear and others disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of tags in one section of my web page and the article goes in the middle. I want to be able to click a tag and have related articles appear in the middle section and the others that are not related to disappear.

For example, if someone clicks on a link called "skateboarding" all the articles that have a anchor name "skateboarding" will appear and the others disappear. But have it work any tag that I will make in the future. Hopefully that makes sense. Here is the page: http://idunlap.com/social-media-template/index.html

Comment: you'll need to use css and javascript and html to achieve your desired goals

Comment: I am not good at javascript. I only know HTML and CSS

Comment: then you'll need to get better at javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your anchors classnames is `articles`, you can simply create javascript function that loops trought article to display corresponding anchors and hide others.
the can be like this.

```
       //First map you articles in an array
   var nodes = [].map.call(document.getElementsByClassName("articles"), function(x){return x;});
  //Create function now.
  function filterArticles(x){
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
   if(x[i].style.display = "inline" || !x[i].style.display) x[i].style.display = "none"; else x[i].style.display = "inline";
   }

 //Set click handler t all articles.
nodes.forEach(function(x){x.onclick = function(art){ filterArticles(nodes)};
```

However, As said by @Jaromanda, you must get better in javascript, it is the least.

Comment: Ok, Coo!! I will get better at Javascript. I tried codecademy, but still have a bit of trouble. Any recommendations?

Comment: Personaly i used http://w3schools.com to learn EVERYTHING about the web. It has html,  css, javascript, php and so many. Course are done the simpliest way and they are accompanied with example, exercices done very basic, simple way. I started from ZERO.